# How can I get information from a function

Tags: javascript, game-mechanics

Okay, so if I use this code to randomly spawn balls at the top of the screen, how do i get them to move down:

```
var max_bollar = 10;
var i = 0;
var timecounter = 0;
var bollarcounter = 0;
var spawn_delay = 200;
var min_spawn_delay = 25;
var max_spawn_delay = 500;

function spawn(i)
{
    var boll = {x: random(totalWidth), y: random(totalHeight)}
    circle( boll.x, 10, 10, "blue");
    timecounter = 0;
    bollarcounter++;
    max_spawn_delay = ( random(max_spawn_delay - min_spawn_delay ) + min_spawn_delay );
}

function update()
{
    timecounter += 1;
    if(timecounter == spawn_delay && bollarcounter < max_bollar) spawn(bollarcounter);
}
```

I want them to be falling from the top of the screen and the player has to dodge the balls falling. How do I make the balls move or rather how do I get the information of each ball? So I can Add y cordinates and stuff. (I know i need to Add a clearScreen to make the balls move)

I want to make something like this:

```
Boll.y += 10;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array to hold all the balls:

```
var balls = [];
```

When you spawn a ball, include it on the list:

```
function spawn(i)
{
    var boll = {x: random(totalWidth), y: random(totalHeight)}
    circle( boll.x, 10, 10, "blue");
    timecounter = 0;
    bollarcounter++;
    max_spawn_delay = ( random(max_spawn_delay - min_spawn_delay ) + min_spawn_delay );

    // Include the ball on the list
    balls.push(boll);
}
```

Now is very easy to control them, just iterate the array of the balls in the `update` method and do the changes you want:

```
for (var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
    balls[i].y += 5;
};
```

Comment: http://koda.nu/labbet/6356038 what did i do wrong the balls did not go down

Comment: You are not doing as I said, the `update` method is wrong. You need use a use a for loop to interate through the array. You aren't clearing the screen and aren't drawing the balls again.

See the changes on the link.

Comment: Okay Thanks, i am new to coding so i don't get everithing

Comment: Is there any way to make the all balls fall from the top? If there is not I'M happy anyways

Comment: In the `spawm` method, set the `y` to 0.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the balls to the list
2. in `update()` iterate over the list and update each ball's `y` position

Comment: I don't really get it, i am new to coding so Yeah, don't understand how to do it. Sorry

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp